# Receber data e hora sem separadores e converter para formato data

Tags: php, data

Gostaria de ter a data e hora em php, dessa forma:

Exemplo:

Gostaria de receber essa data assim:

`09092017104430`

E gostaria que a saída fosse algo assim:

`09/09/2017 10:44:30`

Answer (score 3):

Use o método `DateTime::createFromFormat`. Você deve passar no primeiro parâmetro o formato de entrada da data. No segundo parâmetro, você deve colocar a string contendo o valor que será interpretado como uma data.

Veja:

```
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmYHis', '09092017104430');


var_dump($data->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'));
```

O estilo acima foi escrito usando OOP. Mas se você preferir, também poderá usar as funções abaixo para fazer isso:

```
$data = date_create_from_format('dmYHis', '09092017104430');


var_dump(date_format($data, 'd/m/Y H:i:s'));
```

Explicação de cada valor usado no formato:

> `d` => dia com dois dígitos
>
> `m` => mês com dois dígitos
>
> `Y` => Ano com 4 dígitos
>
> `H` => Hora atual, de 0 a 23, com dois dígitos
>
> `i` => minuto com dois dígitos
>
> `s` => segundo com dois dígitos